OneToMany on Map<Enum, Entity> in Hibernate (spring boot) creates unique constraint?
I am creating the backend for a boardgame in Spring Boot. This boardgame can have 1 to n players that each get a color. Player is an entity, just as Game. Color is an enum. It seemed to me a good idea to store the players of a game in a Map<Color, Player>. This allows me to dynamically store the players with the color as key and gives me cleaner code.
However, if I use the following code:
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Player {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    private String name;

}

public enum Colors {
    A, B, C, D
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Game {
    // ...

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Map<Color, Player> players;
    
    // ...
}

I seem not to be able to create 2 games with the same players playing with the same colors. E.g. when a game exists with A = Alice and B = Bob, then I can't create a second game with A = Alice and B = Bob:
SQL Error: 23505, SQLState: 23505
Unique index or primary key violation: "PUBLIC.CONSTRAINT_INDEX_F ON PUBLIC.GAME_PLAYERS(PLAYERS_ID NULLS FIRST) VALUES ( /* 2 */ UUID '3c6a13f6-2465-435b-bd4d-7e87525d4e29' )"; SQL statement:
    insert into game_players (game_id,players_key,players_id) values (?,?,?) [23505-224]

Digging into the problem, I see that Hibernate has created the following table to store the OneToMany mapping:
create table game_players (players_key tinyint not null check (players_key between 0 and 3), game_id uuid not null, players_id uuid not null unique, primary key (players_key, game_id))

The unique constraint on players_id is preventing the addition of the second game color-player combo's. The primary key is (players_key, game_id), so why is this unique constraint present and where does it come from? How can I best solve this?

In players_id uuid not null unique where unique came from?

In your case, using the @MapKeyColumn annotation should help avoid the unique constraint on the Player entity.
The issue occurs because Hibernate sets a unique constraint on the players_id column when generating the table for the OneToMany mapping. Therefore, after creating a game with A = Alice and B = Bob, you cannot create a second game using Alice and Bob.
Game
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Game {
    // ...

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "color")
    private Map<Color, Player> players;

    // ...

}


This article will provide you with a lot of valuable information.

Moreover, if players can participate in games with multiple colors, it would be advisable to switch to using @ManyToMany. However, since ManyToMany relationships in JPA do not support maps directly, it appears we'll need to create a Join Entity to implement this.
Player
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Player {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "player")
    private List<ColorPlayer> colorPlayers;
}

Colors
public enum Colors {
    A, B, C, D
}

Join Entity
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ColorPlayer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Colors color;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "player_id")
    private Player player;
}

Game
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Game {
    // ...

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<ColorPlayer> colorPlayers;

    // ...
}

In terms of object-relational mapping (ORM) frameworks like Hibernate or JPA, a join entity can also carry additional information about the relationship between entities. For example, in a relationship between Game and Player entities, a ColorPlayer join entity could store the game's duration, outcome, and other relevant details.
If you need more information plz feel free to let me know. 
have a nice day - kevin
